# How to Handle the Handler in SeekBar

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

i am developing Call recording application. i am managed to show the audio files in ListView and able to play in MediaPlayer. know i am having a problem in SeekBar Handler. when i play the audio file, the MediaPlayer and SeekBar works absolutely right but when i close my application the Handler of SeekBar remains active. how can i stop the Handler.

```
private void playSong(String string)
                throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException,
                IllegalStateException, IOException {

            // seekBar
            setContentView(R.layout.dialog_activity);
            startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
            stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
            seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
            startButton.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            stopButton.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

            // MediaPlayer
            mp.reset();
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setDataSource(string);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());

            try {
                seekUpdation();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "SeekUpdation " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        }

        Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    seekUpdation();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Runnable ", "error in Runnable =" + e.toString());
                }
            }
        };
```

thats the Handler who remain active after closing the application.

```
        public void seekUpdation() {

            seekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
            seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded" + seekHandler,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer by my self.

we have to change the code from this

```
 Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                seekUpdation();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Runnable ", "error in Runnable =" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    public void seekUpdation() {

        seekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
        seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded" + seekHandler,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});
}
```

to this

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {

                  public void run() {
                     seekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
                     seekHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                  }
               };

        private void seekUpdation() {

            seekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
            seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded" + seekHandler,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```